# Autenticar com session storage

Tags: jquery, html5, session

Tenho uma tela de login, onde se o usuario logar é gravado uma session storage com a informaçao necessaria, tambem vi como posso ler essa informação gravada, porem como faço para ao abrir uma pagina atraves da URL verificar se a session storage foi gravada, se esta ok, deixa abrir a pagina, senao redireciona para outra. Estou usando html5, javascritp, css, nessa aplicação não posso usar uma linguagem clint server, tipo PHP, ASP NET ou outra qualquer, tenho que trabalhar exclusivamente do lado do cliente, sempre consumindo o webservice usando ajax.

Obrigado

Comment: Eu acho que é um caso de utilizar OAuth ou Json Web Token, cara. Não sei se seria seguro salvar as informações do usuário no Session Storage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso o login esteja correto, crie uma session no seu script da página de login

```
sessionStorage.setItem('Intelider', 'Sistemas');
```

Agora é só testar se a sessão expirou nas páginas protegidas:

```
  //recupera a session    
  var data = sessionStorage.getItem('Intelider');

  if (data == null){
     //exemplo
      window.location.href = 'suaPaginaDeLogin.html'; 
  }
```

Comment: Valeu @Leo Caracciolo, funcionou perfeito, obrigado